# How to increase depth of JSON device state in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

**Maximum depth of JSON device state documents.**
**The maximum number of levels in the desired or reported section of the JSON device state document is 5.**

```
"desired": {
    "one": {
        "two": {
            "three": {
                "four": {
                    "five":{
                    }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

**But I want use the data like below way.**

```
"desired": {
    "one": {
        "two": {
            "three": {
                "four": {
                    "five":{
                        "six":{
                            "seven":{
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

If it increases more than five in json device state. I am getting error as follows.

```
{
    "message": "Json contains too many levels of nesting. Maximum allowed is 6.",
    "code": "InvalidRequestException",
    "time": "2018-09-21T16:57:43.546Z",
    "requestId": "464bf996-2b8d-a258-0d41-9c56ad644bd3",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 26.035247904464033
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-write in the following way:

```
{
    'desired.one.two.three.foure.five.six.seven': 'value'
}
```

Comment: what if I have arrays in between objects and objects in arrays?

Comment: Can you provide an example for us? Thanks!